# What are the risks in eliminating sync over async?

Tags: c#, async

I'm reviewing changes to a widely used library, which are supposed to be refactorings, and so we want to minimize the risk of introducing any accidental regression. Of course, there are changes from this:

```
    if (!BlobExists())
```

to this:

```
    if (!await BlobExists(cancellationToken))
```

This looks like an impure refactoring - even ignoring the `CancellationToken` parameter, the return type of `BlobExists` must have changed to `Task<bool>`. So, whether the code *blocks the thread while the blob existence is checked on some other thread* has changed. But, I also know in normal usage the intent of the code is probably the same, and in most cases we are *unlikely* to depend on the thread-blocking sync-waiting-on-async-result behavior.

That is, at least we are unlikely to *know* that we intended to depend on the thread-blocking sync-over-async behavior. What are the risk scenarios here, where we might *unknowingly* actually be depending on that behavior, or in general, unpleasantly surprised to find we've introduced a bug?

Comment: Any code that you turn into an await that sets something up could introduce a race condition, imagine if for some reason BlobExists previously set some variable somewhere else, and later code in the same thread checked that variable. Now there's scope for that check to happen before the setup.

Comment: Thoughts aloud, does the `BlobExists` supports being called concurrently? Can the app change state in a way that while `BlobExists` is running it would render the code inside IF wrong?

Comment: A whole bunch of stuff could break, but... you are testing those things still work even if your change is just a comment right?.... righhhtttt????

Comment: @Ewan If you mean automated tests, of course, then run on every pull request! But if you mean exhaustive or manual testing, you're joking right? This code is depended on by like, over 100 different scenarios. Hence, one purpose of the question - what are the risks we should be focusing on, in order to test in a more intelligent way?

Comment: You may find the behaviour of async/await varies between different kinds of apps due to `SynchronizationContext` - this old blog post from MS explains the potential issues - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/

Comment: dude, you are right, this change could totaly compile fine, pass your unit tests and then break in real life because you miss an await, or have a deadlocking issue. You will **HAVE** to check everything. I don't think there are any shortcuts or static analysis tools that will magic it away. Nothing in your draft answer can be tested for other than running a unit test that fails

Comment: *we want to minimize the risk of introducing any accidental regression*  => Then get this book. Buy it, keep it, write in it, treasure it:   [Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/refactoring-improving-the/0201485672/).  If you learn only 5 of the 30+ explicit refactoring recipes then you'll know 98% more than 100% of the people who ever said "Not a lot of code right here, let's refactor that method into it."

Comment: @radarbob Yup, got that one, its a classic.

Answer (score 2):

For a concrete example of a race condition that could be introduced, consider

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        setupStuff();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine(x); // 7
    }
    
    public static int x = 2;
    
    public static void setupStuff() {
        if (BlobExists()) {
            x = 7;
        }
    }
    
    public static Boolean BlobExists() {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
        return true;
    }
}
```

vs

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        setupStuff();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        Console.WriteLine(x); // 2
    }
    
    public static int x = 2;
    
    public static async void setupStuff() {
        if (await BlobExists()) {
            x = 7;
        }
    }
    
    public static System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Boolean> BlobExists() {
        return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() => {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                return true;
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: This will produce a warning because you are not awaiting setupStuff() . I would consider missing await an incorrect usage and not really acceptable example how adding async causes race conditions.

Comment: @Euphoric True. but isn't incorrect usage exactly the sort of thing being asked about? The place I work at there's a million warnings in the project and (almost) everyone ignores them. Of course this isn't ideal... but I imagine my work isn't alone in being in this situation. That there's a warning seems like a thing that Tim can do to assuage his worries, namely check through the warnings for any newly introduced errors along the lines of...

Comment: yeah "you forgot to await" is prob the #1 problem that would be introduced

Answer (score 0):

Since I want a quick answer to my question, I'm going to start drafting one. I fully expect a better answer will be posted by someone else in the fullness of time...

Let's try to figure it out from first principles by describing more fully the change we are making. Let's also ease the discussion slightly by renaming the Task-returning version of the function `BlobExistsAsync()`, and calling it 'the async version'.

What do the async version and sync version really do?

1. They both start running on the calling thread, likely, but not necessarily a worker thread. It could be some other thread, like an IO thread, or UI thread. We don't know.
2. At some point, each implementation sends a request, or in reality, they call an API, to talk over the network. They most probably call *different APIs* under the hood (difference #1). Because they call different APIs, they do some different preparation for this, like in the async case, a continuation function has to be generated (difference #2).
3. The continuation function may or may not actually run, because the API may just return with a result immediately, this is either success, or failure. In this case, both functions probably just return this result back to the calling thread immediately.
4. But what else could happen at this point, when there is no immediate result? Well, it depends on which API we called. In the sync case, the API *steals the thread*. The current thread keeps running, but it's no longer running our code - its either stuck running the API we called, OR just sleeping waiting for some signal to wake it up again. While it is doing this, it *still holds any locks or mutexes that we acquired that are associated to that thread.* Also, we have no certainty the API will ever return, it could deadlock, and our thread would certainly never get to run again.
5. But, in the async case, the API *yields the thread* by returning us a task object, which represents the unfinished work. Eventually, we think, the task will get completed. It's possible to decide to *await* the task. It's also possible not to, if we don't want to, or we don't want to check the result directly, at least not until later. Either way, we have our thread back, and the task has a continuation function that it can call when it is done. We can continue do more work, while still holding any locks, or mutexes etc. that are associated to this current thread.
6. We can also release those locks, if we have any. We will mainly do this in a *race* with the calling of the continuation function, when the task completes, so unless we do something extra we can't assume those locks are still held.
7. We also can't assume those locks are NOT still held. (Especially deadlock risk....)
8. The continuation function may get called back on a thread pool worker thread, or an IO thread, or even some other thread. We don't really know, by default, when we are talking about the raw continuation. If we want to be very precise about the kind of context or thread our callback completion runs, there could be extra work involved, like (ick!) using SynchronizationContexts, Posting window message, or using some other dispatch mechanism to offload the work.
9. When we finally use `await` on the Task, the framework sets up certain things (like SynchronizationContexts or ExecutionContexts) by convention, so that we get called back in the 'least surprising' way possible. Unless we tell it not to, by using `.ConfigureAwait(false)`...
10. Finally, we get called back by the framework, and our 'continuation' runs, i.e. the rest of the method that we introduced async to.

So, to try to summarize some of the interesting differences that might somehow relate to bugs or changes in behavior of your code:

- your code can be running a different thread, or a different thread from before. This can mean that e.g. it no longer holds a lock acquired via `Monitor.TryEnter()` or its ilk, that you expected it to (because its owned by a different thread), and
  a) you probably won't be able to release it since your thread isn't the one associated with it any more. (Luckily the compiler knows not to let you do this the `lock` statement way.)
  b) you will read different values from `[ThreadStatic]` fields than you used to
  c) your code is now running on an IO thread or UI thread and can block the IO threads instead of jut blocking the worker threads that it used to be running on.
- your code has now introduced *wait dependencies* between threads (or categories of threads) which may not have existed before. This can contribute to circular wait dependencies, or 'spiral of death' issues.

Comment: I think you need to brush up on implications of what async really does. True, there are many threads in the background. But the code still executes synchronously. Adding async will not introduce new race conditions. I'm sure you cannot create a specific code that demostrates a possible deadlock that exists with async but doesn't exist using synchronous variant.

Comment: @Euphoric Thanks, I think I need to clarify that the 'race' worry is mainly for the cases where you *don't* immediately await on the returned task, but do other work first.

Comment: I wouldn't use excuse of bad dev practices like ignoring warnings and not using the tool correctly as a problems with the tool itself. Using "async void" and not awaiting tasks is not a right way to using async/await https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12144077/async-await-when-to-return-a-task-vs-void

Comment: @Euphoric Ignoring warnings has hardly anything to do with the question, since you won't get any warnings just from introducing async/await, if you do it the usual way. And the example in the question awaits in the usual way.